# How to create sort function in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create sort function in my VueJS code. It has these fields: `Price: Low to High`, `Price: High to Low`.

So, this is my `template`:

```
<div name="divSortBy">
        <span>
          Sort by:
        </span>
        <select v-model="sort" name="selectSortBy">
          <option
            v-for="item in sortedList"
            :key="item.id"
            name="selectOptionsSortBy"
            :value="item"
            @click="sortBy"
            v-text="item.title"
          ></option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

This in `data() { return {} }`:

```
sortByItems: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Price: Low to High',
      sort: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Price: High to Low',
      sort: 2
    }
  ],
  sort: null
productsList: [],
```

And this is `computed`:

```
computed: {
sortedList() {
  // FILTER HERE
  if (this.sort) {
    if (this.sort.id === '1') {
      console.log(this.sort.title) // console.log for tests
      this.productsList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price
      })
    } else if (this.sort.id === '2') {
      console.log(this.sort.title)
    }
  }

  return this.sortByItems
}
```

As you can see, I was trying to sort it by this function, but it doesn't work:

```
this.productsList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price
      }
```

By the way, `productsList: []` is the list of objects, so, I need to sort it by `price` field and then show sorted products on page.

Thanks!

Comment: where is your `data`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean is without knowing the structure of `this.productsList`, the sort wouldn't be easy.

Comment: Every object in `productsList` has 2 fields. `Price` and `name`. I want to sort it by price, and then, show sorted on page.

Comment: `low to high` and `high to low` I get it we can do but how do you sort the array if user selected `newest first` or `Oldest first`. There is no date property?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I'm gonna create these fields later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise the sort algorithm by passing the comparator function

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cache-v1vio?file=/src/App.vue)

```
if (this.sort.id === "1") {
  return [...this.productsList].sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
  });
} else if (this.sort.id === "2") {
   return [...this.productsList].sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.price - a.price;
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @BL4DERUNNER I've added the codesandbox in the answer. Check it there change `sorting option` from `1` or `2`

Comment: Still doesn't work, the same result for `Price: Low to High` and `Price: High to Low`

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code, So it would be easier to understand if you could add yout code here?